# CMake find_package for FindLibXml2

Tags: c++, cmake, libxml2, clion

I'm trying to create a CMake file that will detect the location of libxml2. From what see in examples and CMake documentation the find_package simply works. I'm running CLion on Ubuntu, the libxml2 is installed using apt-get, the FindLibXml2.cmake is located under CMake's modules. However CMake returns cryptic message:

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FindLibXml2"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> FindLibXml2Config.cmake
> findlibxml2-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "FindLibXml2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "FindLibXml2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "FindLibXml2" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it   has been installed.

Why it is trying to find this `-config` file? what I'm doing wrong?

CMake snippet

> find_package(FindLibXml2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

I've also tried

> find_package(FindLibXml2 REQUIRED)

Not sure which one to use

Comment: Could you share the CMake commands you use to search for the package, ie. the find_package() invocation?

Comment: sure. question updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have the `Find` in `FindLibXml2`; do:

```
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html):

> CMake searches for a file called `Find<package>.cmake`